# Create line/points at contacts between polygons of certain attribute?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

I have a shapefile of polygons representing geologic map units. I want to create line/point features along the contact between two particular units (polygons identified by attribute code) so I can get those elevations off a DEM.

How can I create line features only along the contact between specific polygon attributes?

Comment: You can use polygon to line https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003t000000 if you have an advanced license with a neighbor_option of IDENTIFY_NEIGHBORS on the selected polygons. Lines between two selected polygons will have a left_fid and right_fid, lines that are not between selected polygons will have -1 in either of left_fid or right_fid.

Comment: Feature to line works better, producing nice edges between polygons.